# AngularJS template switching

Tags: angularjs, adaptive-design

Our client wants a responsive website, but he wants to change and move so much content that we will run into bootstrap limitations.

With bootstrap you can show and hide blocks and move them around with offset, but somehow it has it's limitations. It is a demanding client that will not respect such limitations so we are looking for other options.

To avoid creating duplicate content and still have the ability to give the mobile/desktop experience our team came up with AngularJS.

Our JSON data and Angular controllers can stay the same, but we only need to switch views if it is on mobile/tablet/desktop.

Is there a good stable solution to get this working?
And can we test it like we test responsive design by resizing the browser, or is useragent detection the only solution?
That would be a pain during testing, since we need then many devices or emulators to test.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom directive for this.

```
app.directive('responsiveTemplate', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var mobile = attr.mobile;
            var desktop = attr.desktop;
            scope.template = desktop;

            $(window).resize(function() {
                if (windowSizeIsDesktop() && scope.template != desktop) {
                    scope.template = desktop;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
                else if (windowSizeIsMobile() && scope.template != mobile) {
                    scope.template = mobile;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Use as an element

```
<responsive-template desktop="desktop.html" mobile="mobile.html"></responsive-template>
```

I have not defined the `windowSize` functions though they are trivial to implement

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use ng-if for this, but I'd make sure you need it first and can't simply use css / media queries for what you're describing. Here's an example of the ng-if logic:

```
<body ng-app="myApp"> 
   <div ng-controller="ctrl" >
      <div ng-if="isWide()">
         <p>Wide Content</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="!isWide()">
          <p>Narrow Content</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

And the js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $window) {    
   $scope.isWide = function() {
        return $window.innerWidth > 500; //your breakpoint here.
   }

   angular.element($window).on('resize', angular.bind($scope, $scope.$apply));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gq2obdcq/8/

Just drag the split pane to see the results in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, almost what we are looking for. But not really separated templates. Probably BackboneJS is a better option? “Angular uses the view to derive behavior whereas Backbone uses behavior to drive the view”

Comment: I don't think that's a true statement about angular. I also don't really understand how it relates to your question. Perhaps if you update your question with some code examples, I could help you derive a better solution. I would not advise choosing a new technology for the issue that (I think) you're describing, unless you have more experience in that technology...

Comment: Wel the point is that we want to avoid mixing mobile and desktop content blocks in one view. Your <div ng-controller="ctrl"> container stays at the same position. No matter on what device you are.
Mobile and Desktop templates are totally different in block order, so switching to a totally new view file would be better.

Comment: Shot in the dark as I'm still unclear what you're after, but I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gq2obdcq/15/ - you can move the ng-controller to the body tag if you're looking to get rid of that div and you can define different views in an ng-include in tandem with the ng-if. At this point, it's pretty similar to your solution below, but you have different routes entirely it looks like for mobile/desktop which I would think is an SEO nightmare

Comment: You could also use matchMedia (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) which is like css media queries for javascript. That way, you don't have to bind to the resize event.

Answer (score 1):

```
$routeProvider.
 when('/:menu/:page', {
     controller:HandleCtrl,
     template:'<div ng-include="templateUrl">Loading...</div>'
 }).
```

Combined with:

```
function HandleCtrl($scope, $routeParams){
 $scope.templateUrl = $routeParams.menu +'/'+ $routeParams.page + '.html'
}
```

Would this be safe?
Inside the controller I can decide what html file I want to use as template